# Accessing the wind speed at each turbine

Tags: floris

I am looking for a way to access the wind speed in each of my turbines. Even though, as far I am concerned, floris works for only one wind speed as input, you should have a way to be able to see the wind speeds at waked turbines, as you need to calculate it in the end to reach the overall wind farm power. Hence, I went to the documentation and what I could find was that on floris.simulation.farm you have a getter that should be able to return a list of the wind speeds over the wind farm. This can be achieved by:

```
wind_speed = floris.farm.wind_speed()
```

However, when I try to follow the instructions, I get only one integer, which is the wind speed that was set. So, is it possible to get the value of the wind speed at each turbine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [v1.1.4](https://github.com/NREL/floris/releases/tag/v1.1.4) of FLORIS, the code:

```
wind_speed = floris.farm.wind_speed()
```

returns the wind speed of the wind farm, which as you state is the same as the wind speed that was set either in the input file or in code. This is because this is a property of the `farm` class that is meant to return the farm level wind speed (see the [source code](https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/v1.1.4/floris/simulation/farm.py#L166) for the definition of the property).

### Get Turbine Velocities Directly From FLORIS Object

In order to get the wind speed at individual turbines, you can use:

```
turbine_wind_speeds = [turb.average_velocity for turb in floris.farm.turbines]
```

which will return a list containing the average velocity of each turbine.

### Get Turbine Coordinates Directly From FLORIS Object

The velocities are returned in the order that the turbine locations were specified. To know the specific turbine that a velocity is associated with, you can get the turbine coordinates from the turbine map:

```
turbine_coords = [(coord.x1, coord.x2) for coord in floris.farm.turbine_map.coords]
```

The first velocity returned in `turbine_wind_speeds` is the velocity at the first set of turbine coordinates in `turbine_coords`, and so on.

### Example Script Showing Methods

A full script showing the usage of these methods and their outputs can be found below, using the [example input file](https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/v1.1.4/examples/example_input.json) included in the FLORIS examples folder, and the [`FlorisInterface`](https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/v1.1.4/floris/tools/floris_utilities.py#L20) class which has several other helper methods for interacting with FLORIS objects.

**Example Python Script**

```
# Import the tools module of FLORIS
import floris.tools as wfct

# Initialize the FLORIS interface 'fi'
fi = wfct.floris_utilities.FlorisInterface("example_input.json")

# Calculate wake
fi.calculate_wake()

# Retrieve and print the individual turbine velocities
turbine_wind_speeds = [turb.average_velocity for turb in fi.floris.farm.turbines]
print('turbine_wind_speeds: ', turbine_wind_speeds)

# Retrieve and print the turbine coordinates
turbine_coords = [(coord.x1, coord.x2) for coord in fi.floris.farm.turbine_map.coords]
print('turbine_coords: ', turbine_coords)
```

**Example Output**

```
turbine_wind_speeds:  [7.973632994592287, 5.572642539922095, 7.973632994592287, 5.572642539922095]
turbine_coords:  [(0.0, 0.0), (800.0, 0.0), (0.0, 630.0), (800.0, 630.0)]
```